# Ignoring nan values when creating confidence intervals

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

AS the title suggest, I am trying to create confidence intervals based on a table with a ton of nan values. Here is an example of what I am working with.

```
     Attendence%    2016-10 2016-11 2017-01 2017-02 2017-03 2017-04 ...
Name
Karl                   nan    0.2     0.4     0.5      0.2     1.0  
Alice                  1.0    0.7     0.6     nan      nan     nan   
Ryan                   nan    nan     1.0     0.1      0.9     0.2       
Don                    nan    0.5     nan     0.2      nan     nan  
Becca                  nan    0.2     0.6      0       nan     nan
```

For reference, in my actual dataframe there are more NaNs than not, and they represent months where they did not need to show up, so replacing the values with 0 will affect the result.

Now everytime I try applying a Confidence interval to each name, it it returns the mean as NaN, as well as both intervals.

```
Karl     (nan, nan, nan)
Alice    (nan, nan, nan)
Ryan     (nan, nan, nan)
Don      (nan, nan, nan)
Becca    (nan, nan, nan)
```

Is there a way to filter out the NaN so it just applies the formula while not taking into account the NaN values. So far what I have been doing has been the following:

unstacked being the table i visually represented.

```
def mean_confidence_interval(unstacked, confidence=0.9):
    a = 1.0 * np.array(unstacked)
    n = len(a)
    m, se = np.mean(a), scipy.stats.sem(a)
    h = se * scipy.stats.t.ppf((1 + confidence) / 2., n-1)
    return m, m-h, m+h

answer = unstacked.apply(mean_confidence_interval)
answer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.nanmean` instead of `np.mean`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html

And for `scipy.stats.sem(a)`, replace it with  pass `scipy.stats.sem(a, nan_policy='omit')`.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.sem.html